# Android clip Picture to Bitmap. Is Possible?

Tags: android, svg, bitmap, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I have a Picture object, loaded from an SVG file, and I have set hardwareAccelerated=false to make it works on all devices.

Since there is a bug on android 4.0.4, I have to convert the Picture to Bitmap and I do that, in this way:

```
...
...
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    ...
    ...

    //myPicture size is 9000x5000 but I want to display only this portion
    clipRect.set(50, 50, 370, 530);
    Bitmap bmp = getBitmapFromPicture(myPicture, clipRect);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
    bmp.recycle();
    ...
    ...
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromPicture(Picture picture, RectF clipRect) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(Math.round(clipRect.width()), Math.round(clipRect.height()), Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawPicture(picture);
}
```

Now I want to clip the Picture because I want to display only the visible screen part of it.
But the canvas.drawPicture does not accept srcRect parameter.
How is it possible to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

By translate the canvas: `canvas.translate(-50, -50)` it seems that translate the bitmap, too.[image: result picture]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a transform on the Canvas.

To move the portion of the picture at 50,50 down so it is on the bitmap (ie. at 0,0), just do:

```
canvas.translate(-50, -50);
```

So your method becomes:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromPicture(Picture picture, RectF clipRect)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(Math.round(clipRect.width()),
                                        Math.round(clipRect.height()),
                                        Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.translate(-clipRect.left, -clipRect.top);
    canvas.drawPicture(picture);
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but it results in a black border top-left. I think because it translate the bitmap, then it draw the picture filling the bounds of the canvas and finally restore the bitmap position but the 50,50 (top, left) hasn't been draw

Comment: I had an error. I should have said 'top' not 'bottom'. Not sure if it changes anything for you though.  Which library are you using. Is it drawing anything at all.  Your description of what is happening is not very useful.  Can you post a screenshot somewhere?